# How to merge with merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, fast-forward

When I try to merge with command:

```
git merge --no-ff -m <message> <source-branch>
```

I get message: Already up to date.
but it's not!

When I'm trying to merge like:

```
git merge origin <branch-name>
```

branch is merged fast-forward.

But I need merge commit. Please help me how to fix it.

Comment: `git merge origin somebranch` means `git merge origin/HEAD somebranch`: this does an *octopus merge*. That's not what you want. Show the actual command you're running, what it produces, what you expected it to produce instead, and describe why you had that expectation: see [ask].

Comment: As well as what torek said, a general tip: change one thing at a time. You should be able to add the `--no-ff` option to whatever command is giving you a fast-forward merge, but the commands you show vary in other ways.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, note you need to *undo* your previous fast-forward merge before you can redo it with `--no-ff`. (And if you did an octopus merge you'll probably want to undo that regardless...)